# Github Pages not found after renaming repository

Tags: github-pages

I was publishing user pages with GitHub pages. After renaming my repository from `username.github.io` to `username.github.io__`, and renaming back my repo to `username.github.io` my pages are not showing up anymore.

The purpose of renaming my repo was to unpublish my pages for a short period of time.

Can someone give me a solution to republish my pages?

Comment: I think you should ask to github support. Also try to disable and re-enable pages in repo setting, that is the correct way of putting your site offline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was just needed to update with empty commit :

```
git commit -m 'rebuild pages' --allow-empty
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

While an extra commit solves the problem, you should note a few things.

**First**, to fix the issue, push a new commit.

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Empty commit"
git push
```

**Second**, make sure that the branch you committed is the `master` branch. For example, in my case, I make changes to the `develop` branch, and then I had to merge `develop` to `master` so that the actual page gets built again.